# Google is displaying a URL in my site's index with the cache of that result being completely different

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, search

Ok, this may turn out to be a silly question but I have observed Google displaying a URL in the index with the cache of that result being completely different when it shouldn't even be there in the first place.

Description:

I built a random function for the website `docur.co`

The function initiates with a request to:

`http://docur.co/random`

The robots are blocked from this URL:

`http://docur.co/robots.txt`

However Google has followed this URL and produced the following search result:

[image: https://goo.gl/BCyOml]

This is the cache:

[image]

My question is: Can anyone tell me what exactly is going on here? As aforementioned, I may have done something wrong...

Update:

Maybe adding the re="nofollow" directly to the anchor on top of the robots directive will ensure that Google will not follow the URL?

Comment: Is it possible that google crawled and indexed this link before you setup your robots.txt? Have you tried removing that 1 url using the removal tool https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals ?

Comment: The site is very sensitive about Google results so the robots file was updated before i pushed my code live. 100% sure.

Comment: If you use the removal tool on that URL does Google re index it just with different content (whatever random happens to load)?

Comment: I here you point.  However Google should not even be following the URL according to themselves: http://postimg.org/image/np474rrgx/ So what?

Comment: *Hear I find it really astonishing that Google will check out nofollowed URL's and process them.

Comment: I've encountered strange I dexing behaviour like this before and many times Google will actually correct the issue over time(a couple weeks or so). How long has this been happening?

Comment: @Analog I have found that the Remove URL is so slow that it can take months. I waited as much as 2 months before giving up. Has it gotten any better?? With robots.txt, the next time it is read from a site and it has changed, it will be matched against the site's URLs within the index to see if anything should be removed. I am not sure if that is real-time, semi-real-time, or batch. I suspect it is semi-real-time trigger based. This means that in theory, once the robots.txt file is read, the URL should disappear within a reasonable period. I expect 1 day.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your robots.txt file.

On line 11 you have Allow: /, a robots.txt file doesn't say what files and directories you can allow, only what you can disallow. The only supported commands for the robots.txt file are "User-agent" and "Disallow".

As the Disallow: /random command is after the invalid command it is possible the Google Searchbot detected an invalid command and because it couldn't process it stopped processing the entire robots.txt file as if it didn't exist at all.

You can validate your robots.txt file using a tool such as the one located at http://tool.motoricerca.info/robots-checker.phtml

As for why the cacheed version is different to the live version the cached version it what Google see's at the time the spider went through which in the case of your cached link was 6 April 2016 at 16:05:27 GMT.

A new version of your robots.txt file which you could use is...

```
#The date is August 29th, 1997.
#Robots have taken over the world and documentaries cease to be created by humans.
#what will happen next?

 #Want to join the Docur team?
#E-mail jonbonsilver\\//at\\//gmail\\//dot\\//com

#Full access for the internet archive. 

User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /random

#Every robot that honours the robots.txt standard:

User-agent: *

#Request file from Docur once every second:

Crawl-delay: 1

#Disallowed urls:

#Lets not send bots on a random documentary mission:

Disallow: /random

Disallow: /new-documentaries
#Above is a temp line due to indexing problems. 
Disallow: /?page
Disallow: /live-search
Disallow: /vote
Disallow: /favourite
Disallow: /watch-later
Disallow: /save-list
Disallow: /comment
Disallow: /commentlike
Disallow: /commentdislike
Disallow: /add-review
Disallow: /submit-review
Disallow: /add-to/*
Disallow: /post-list
Disallow: /edit-list
Disallow: /documentary-search
Disallow: /new-list-item
Disallow: /settings
Disallow: /notificationread
Disallow: /documentary/*/l
Disallow: */newest
Disallow: */oldest
Disallow: */highest
Disallow: */lowest
```

Comment: Nice catch! Oddly, we get a fair number of robots.txt errors here. I have seen some references to sites that are technically correct, but misleading or confusing. Some start with disallowing everything then allowing specific things which is easy to screw up. I have also seen some bad advice too.

Comment: PlanetScale @ ia_archiver is alexa bot not Googlebot, and he already using User-agent: * which indicate all polite bots like Googlebot, MSNbot, baidubot etc. and for that useragent he is already using Disallow. @ John do one thing, Go to this [URL](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch), select your properties(Hope you already added your site in Google Search Console), then put random and click on fetch and render tools, and tell us whether it is displayed blocked or not.

Comment: @Goyllo - Please take a careful look at what I said. I didn't say that ia_archiver is the Googlebot, as I am well aware that it isn't, all I said was that having Allow: / doesn't meet the standard, breaks validation, and could be what is causing the issue with the Googlebot, if the Googlebot is programmed to follow the standard.

Comment: @Goyllo  http://postimg.org/image/np474rrgx/ i haven't changed the file according to PlanetScales' recommendations yet...

Comment: I knew it, you have already blocked that random URL, now let me know, you want to hide that URL from search result?, because that URL already redirect to another one. If that content already exit in your site then do 301 redirect to proper documentary content otherwise just use 410 Gone error.

Comment: @closetnoc Why is Google adhering to the rest of file then? Looking at Google's robots file reveals that they are using the "allow" directive too! http://www.google.com/robots.txt Chronologically the first thing that Google is addressed by is disallow: /random